# Problem with Firebase App Check : App is not registered - Next.js integration

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, next.js, firebase-app-check

I followed [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-enterprise-provider) to implement Firebase App Check in my Next.js (v14) project :

```js
// firebase/app.js

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaV3Provider } from "firebase/app-check";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
  databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL,
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// add this condition to prevent 'document is not defined' error on SSR
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  initializeAppCheck(app, {
    provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY
    ),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
  });
}
```

When I run my project locally or in production i get these errors :

```js
POST https://content-firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxx/apps/xxx:exchangeRecaptchaV3Token?key=xxx 400 (Bad Request)
```

```js
@firebase/app-check: AppCheck: Requests throttled due to 400 error. Attempts allowed again after 00m:02s (appCheck/throttled).
```

When I inspect the network tab of the browser I can see this response for the request :

```js
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "App not registered: 1:123xxxxx.", // I made sure this is the right Firebase app id
  "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
```

reCAPTCHA verification cannot be processed.

The problem is that my app is properly registered on Firebase :

[image: confirmation message that the app is properly registered with reCAPTCHA Enterprise]

As well as my website key from reCAPTCHA Enterprise API in the Google Cloud console :

[image: website key properly added in Google Cloud console]

Note that Realtime Database is already implemented in the same project and working fine.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : I was able to reproduce the issue in an [empty repo](https://github.com/pierre-phil/next.js_firebase_starter?tab=readme-ov-file) with a new Firebase project, so I might be missing something regarding the configuration of App Check.

**Repo of the reproduction** : https://github.com/pierre-phil/next.js_firebase_starter?tab=readme-ov-file

Comment: In the Google Cloud Console, ensure that the API key used in the apiKey field of your firebaseConfig has no restrictions that prevent it from being used with the App Check API. If there are any restrictions, make sure that the Firebase services and the reCAPTCHA API are allowed.

Comment: Can you share a repo of the reproduction?

Comment: Can it be related with google services json?

Comment: The API key is not restricted. Here is the repo of the reproduction : https://github.com/pierre-phil/next.js_firebase_starter?tab=readme-ov-file